# Do an API call every few seconds using the Context API and React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it possible to set an auto-refresh interval every few seconds when using the Context API from React? The getData() function runs axios.get() on the API, but still when I try setInterval() and cleanup in the return function of the useEffect hook, it doesn't clean up the interval. getData() sets to the app level state the current and loading variables.

I simply want to refresh and re-do the API call every few seconds. I tried with the useRef() hook and I got it to working, but still the useEffect doesn't clear up the interval once it's finished.

I want to access the current property in the return function of the component and display some data every time an API call is ran.

Here's the code:

```
const { loading, current, getData } = appContext;
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getData();
      console.log('updated');
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line // also tried without the []
```

getData() code:

```
const getData = async () => {
    setLoading();

    const res = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_APIT);

    dispatch({ type: GET_CURRENT, payload: res.data });
  };
```

Comment: You posted a code example where the effect returns `undefined` instead of a cleanup function. Surely it'd be more useful if you showed an attempt to clear the interval.

Comment: @LeopoldsaysReinstateMonica Pasted the wrong snippet, updated the original post.

Comment: FYI, you should be able to pass `getData` in your dependency array without issue, unless that function is changing?

Comment: @Nick I tried to pass getData into the dependency array, but still it doesn't clear the interval on cleanup. Updated the code with the getData function code.

Comment: @dynamitem I didn't think it'd solve your problem, but just wanted to point out you probably don't need to have the lint-disabling code there

Comment: Are you certain about the problem is caused by interval not cleared? Will it possible because your `getData` dispatch the action which will alter `current` cause re-render?

Answer (score 1):

I  had a similar problem and I used to solution described here: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Here is a simple example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

function App() {
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState(2000);

  useInterval(() => {
    // Do some API call here
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('API call');
    }, 500);
  }, intervalTime);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setIntervalTime(2000)}>Set interval to 2 seconds</button>
      <button onClick={() => setIntervalTime(null)}>Stop interval</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Using the state variable `intervalTime` you can control the interval time. By setting it to null the interval will stop running.

Comment: Already viewed that specific article, didn't seem to help me.

Comment: @dynamitem You want to periodically trigger an API call and display the data, right? Using a custom useInterval hook reduces boilerplate instead of using useEffect and setInterval.

Comment: Tried the useInterval custom hook, and I agree it reduces the boilerplate code, but still doesn't cancel my interval properly, and continues to run.

Comment: @dynamitem you could make some smaller adjustments to add a functionality to remove the interval again. For example you could define -1 as a value for stopping the interval.

Comment: @dynamitem I updated my answer with a better example. But I am still not 100% sure what you are looking for.